# Multiple selectors when using a variable

Tags: jquery

Within an .each(function(), I'm trying to uncheck checkboxes.
In line 1, I'm setting the value on 2 different Id's and this works fine.
What I want to do, is to unset both of the checkboxes on a single line. i.e take lines 3 & 4 and combine into 1 line.  Line 2 is what I've tried, but it's not working (it doesn't do either of them).
(The 'wsSeq' is created by the server side, so that I get unique ID's on multiple rows).

```
            $('#wsDocRef,#wsSupp').val('');
//          $("'#wsTransferToQuarantine" + wsSeq + ",#wsTransferToSupplier" + wsSeq + "'").attr('checked', false);
            $('#wsTransferToQuarantine' + wsSeq).attr('checked', false);
            $('#wsTransferToSupplier' + wsSeq).attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("'#wsTransferToQuarantine" + wsSeq + ",#wsTransferToSupplier" + wsSeq + "'").attr('checked', false);
```

That isn't too far off, except for the unnecessary quotes. If `wsSeq` is `1`, your selector looks like this:

```
$("'#wsTransferToQuarantine1,#wsTransferToSupplier1'").attr('checked', false);
```

Which is fine, except for the `'` at each end. This should work fine:

```
$("#wsTransferToQuarantine" + wsSeq + ",#wsTransferToSupplier" + wsSeq).attr('checked', false);
```

With all that said, however, it may actually be quicker to do two ID selections than one multiple selection. This kind of optimisation is probably not necessary or a good use of your time.

Comment: When you say quicker, do you mean that the navigation of the DOM will be faster with 2 individual statements, rather than combining into 1 line?  I assumed that by coding them together, that would be more the 'standards' of jquery.

Comment: @Keith Yes, quite plausibly – though you'd have to benchmark it, and that's more effort than it's worth. One ID selection can be handled by `getElementById`, which is ridiculously fast, while two has to be handled by `querySelectorAll`, which is only very fast.

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't aware of that.  Oh well, I'll leave the 2 lines in there then but the question was answered....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#wsTransferToQuarantine' + wsSeq +',#wsTransferToSupplier' + wsSeq ).prop('checked', false);
```

You were just using two extra quotes in your call that are not needed